# New To Rails 3, ajax request with json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I have a controller named CourseRequests which will be accepting an ajax request for the "new" method.

1. Since it will be responding with json, should I use /course_requests/new.json?
2. I don't want to make a template for such a silly json response, how would I do that?
3. What does respond_to do? (I have seen it block style and I understand that, but what about non-block style)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Yes, your JS would be doing something along the lines of:

   ```
   $.getJSON("/course_requests/new.json",...);
   ```
2. You don't have to, you just need to have a respond_to block with JSON handled there.

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.json { render :json => "test" }
   end
   ```
3. Blockless syntax, I think you mean this: http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/ . Basically, you specify what mime types your controller responds to and then you can use the cooler responds_with method.

Comment: You don't need a `respond_to` block in RoR3. Placing `respond_to :html, :json` in the Controller and calling `respond_with([your results])` within the method is sufficient. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods.html#method-i-respond_to